# Update MongoDB Array Data Best Practice

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, query-optimization, pymongo, aws-documentdb

I have a document that has an array of data, and I want to update several data into that array, currently, I'm using array_filters for that, but it looks like my query doesn't work perfectly and needs more optimization. Does anyone know how to write a perfectly optimized query? I'm using DocumentDB (has several limitations on the query)

I tried to use several methods for updating the MongoDB array data, and I found an article that we can update an array data using `array_filters`, but when I do update for 3 months (around 300 records), the operations failed and I'm getting this message

```
Operation terminated due to low available memory
```

Here's my current code

```py
from pymongo import UpdateOne


hotel_id = 1
records = [
    {
        "date": "2021-01-01",
        "room_id": "1",
        "rate_id": "1",
        "price": 100,
        "ref_id": "",
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-01-02",
        "room_id": "1",
        "rate_id": "1",
        "price": 100,
        "ref_id": "",
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-01-03",
        "room_id": "1",
        "rate_id": "1",
        "price": 100,
        "ref_id": "",
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-01-01",
        "room_id": "2",
        "rate_id": "2",
        "price": 100,
        "ref_id": "",
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-01-02",
        "room_id": "2",
        "rate_id": "2",
        "price": 100,
        "ref_id": "",
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-01-03",
        "room_id": "2",
        "rate_id": "2",
        "price": 100,
        "ref_id": "",
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-01-01",
        "room_id": "3",
        "rate_id": "3",
        "price": 100,
        "ref_id": "",
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-01-02",
        "room_id": "3",
        "rate_id": "3",
        "price": 100,
        "ref_id": "",
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-01-03",
        "room_id": "3",
        "rate_id": "3",
        "price": 100,
        "ref_id": "",
    },
]

coll.bulk_write(
    [
        UpdateOne(
            filter={"hotel_id": hotel_id},
            update={
                "$set": {
                    f"data.$[i{index}].{key}": value
                    for index, record in enumerate(records)
                    for key, value in record.items()
                },
            },
            array_filters=[
                {
                    f"i{index}.date": record["date"],
                    f"i{index}.room_id": record["room_id"],
                    f"i{index}.rate_id": record["rate_id"],
                }
                for index, record in enumerate(records)
            ],
        )
    ]
)
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `for key, value in record.items()`? But I doubt the array you would send to `coll.bulk_write` is what you want.  Don't you want multiple `UpdateOne`?

Comment: yes, sorry I'm going to edit it. And I'm using bulk_write to handle the record's chunk